# prevent duplicate batchInsert in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, batch-insert

```
$connection->createCommand()->batchInsert('user', ['name', 'age'], [
    [$names, $ages],
])->execute();
```

I know that i can do a batch insert using the code above in Yii 2. But how can i prevent duplicate entry using batchInsert? For example, if I have a duplicate name, i dont want to insert it in the db

Answer (score 0):

Two possible options:

**1)** Use unique constraint for `name` column in your database table.

That way you just try to execute query and catch exception:

```
try {
    // Your query goes here
} catch (\yii\db\Exception) {
    // Handle error
}
```

[\yii\db\Exception](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-exception.html) is more common database operations related exception, you can use more specific [\yii\db\IntegrityException](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-integrityexception.html).

**2)** Exclude duplicates from array in PHP before feeding data and executing query. Depending on how array is constructed you can do it:

- during building this array in `foreach` for example by checking if item with same name already exists in formed array, if yes - append element to it, otherwise - skip.
- or afterwards using for example [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function.

I recommend first approach, because even you decide to handle duplicates in PHP, according data structure and additional protection in database won't be superfluos.